# Angularjs web app error

Tags: html, angularjs

The angularjs app doesn't show me any result.

It shows me :

```
Name            City            Order Total             joined
{{ cust.name }} {{ cust.city }} {{ cust.orderTotal }}   {{ cust.joined }}
```

What is the reason of this type of error !!!

**Update 1:**

```
function CustController($scope) 
  { 
    $scope.sortBy = 'name'; 
    $scope.reverse = false; 
    $scope.customers = [
        {joined: '240-344-55', name:'jone', city:'usa', orderTotal:'231'},
        {joined: '240-344-55', name:'jone', city:'usa', orderTotal:'231'},    
        {joined: '240-344-55', name:'jone', city:'usa', orderTotal:'231'}
    ];   
    $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
        $scope.sortBy = propName;    
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }; 
}
```

Comment: Please give your complete code

Comment: function CustController($scope) {
    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;

    $scope.customers= [{joined: '240-344-55', name:'jone', city:'usa', orderTotal:'231'},{joined: '240-344-55', name:'jone', city:'usa', orderTotal:'231'},{joined: '240-344-55', name:'jone', city:'usa', orderTotal:'231'}];

    $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
      $scope.sortBy = propName;
      $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
}

Comment: Update code in your question not in comment

Comment: What type of error?  You haven't posted what the error is.  You really need to include your controller and view code your question.

Comment: write your code in your question then its looks good and clean than in comment and please show your full code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $scope approach, then you have to remove "cust." part from your view. It would be `{{ name }} {{ city }}` etc.

But if your view has `ng-controller="CustController as cust"`, that means you are using "controller as" syntax, so you would need to refactor your controller code, changing `$scope.` to `this.` everywhere at least.